# Select values in the month drop down- Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]

Currently working on Selenium web driver and Java. I want to select the option which in the form of date picker. I tried to select the month from the date picker drop down. but it is showing follows **Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"ui-datepicker-month"}
Command duration or timeout: 31 milliseconds**

So i need to make visible the element using java script executor but in the below code i have written as "document.getElementById('ui-datepicker-month') so again it is showing error as **"document.getElementById('') is null**

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="ui-datepicker-title">
<select class="ui-datepicker-month" onchange="DP_jQuery_1391048152193.datepicker._selectMonthYear('#fromDate', this, 'M');">
<option selected="selected" value="0">Jan</option>
<option value="1">Feb</option>
<option value="2">Mar</option>
<option value="3">Apr</option>
<option value="4">May</option>
<option value="5">Jun</option>
<option value="6">Jul</option>
<option value="7">Aug</option>
<option value="8">Sep</option>
<option value="9">Oct</option>
<option value="10">Nov</option>
<option value="11">Dec</option>
</select>
```

Here is the form i tried but it is not working:

```
JavascriptExecutor executor42 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor42.executeScript("document.getElementById('ui-datepicker-month').style.display='block';");
List<WebElement> select42 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.className("ui-datepicker-month"))).getOptions();
((Select) select42).selectByValue("Jun");
```

Below are the stacktrace:

FAILED: Login
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:192)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.(FluentWait.java:94)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.(WebDriverWait.java:66)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.(WebDriverWait.java:40)
    at test.OverviewAndEvolutionPR.performLogin(OverviewAndEvolutionPR.java:525)
    at test.OverviewAndEvolutionPR.Login(OverviewAndEvolutionPR.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, what do you mean "not working"? Nothing happens? Exceptions? Explain it clearly please.

I can't test Java now, but please debug the following:

```
// Why are you doing this? Can't you just click to open?
// I suspect this is why
JavascriptExecutor executor42 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor42.executeScript("document.getElementById('ui-datepicker-month').style.display='block';");

// if your code above works, then do the following
WebElement selectElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("ui-datepicker-month")));

Select select42 = new Select(selectElement);
select42.selectByValue("5");
// or select42.selectByVisibleText("Jun");
```

If you don't want to loop through the options, don't use `getOptions()` and mess with `List<WebElement>`.

Please always look up methods in the API doc [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html).

**selectByValue**

> Select all options that have a value matching the argument. That is, when given "foo" this would select an option like: Bar

**selectByVisibleText**

> Select all options that display text matching the argument. That is, when given "Bar" this would select an option like: Bar

Comment: I tried your above code it showing java.lang.NullPointerException                                        Why I'm adding javascript executor is to make the element visible

Comment: i changed as you given in your answer. Then i got the null pointer exception as i mentioned in above comments.

Comment: Now i removed and checked then only i got the problem of null pointer exception.. Yes i know I'm checking wrongly with id but i just want to know in case of className for JavaScript executor.

Answer (score 1):

I have solution using [QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf)

```
Select select = new Select(new QAFExtendedWebElement("your locator id"))
    .selectByVisibleText("your text from drop down");
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the answer for the entire date picker tab.

Here is the code:

```
Log.info("Clicking on fromDate drop down");
driver.findElement(By.id("fromDate")).click();
WebElement selectElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("ui-datepicker-month")));
Select select42 = new Select(selectElement);
select42.selectByValue("5");
Thread.sleep(6000);

WebElement selectElement1 = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("ui-datepicker-year")));
Select select43 = new Select(selectElement1);
select43.selectByValue("2012");
Thread.sleep(6000);
```

WebElement dateWidget = driver.findElement(By.id("ui-datepicker-div"));
   List columns=dateWidget.findElements(By.tagName("td"));

```
for (WebElement cell: columns){
//Select 13th Date 
if (cell.getText().equals("13")){
cell.findElement(By.linkText("13")).click();
break;
}
}
```

Thanks to @  user1177636..